# xml structure for snmp polling and read xml in java

Tags: java, xml, structure

I am working on snmp polling for which I have designed an xml structure as below. 
I would like to parse and read the xml structure in a java program. Before that I have few concerns

1. Is the xml structure follows good design best practices?
2. how to design the java classes that could read the attached xml file.
3. need to set TBD in the xml tag oid_value after snmp poll program fetches the snmp poll oid value.

Please help me with some sample code to read the xml and update the xml (as indicated in bullet point 3)

xml file goes here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hosts>
       <host>
              <ip>1.1.1.1</ip>
              <port>1161</port>
              <communityString>testcomm</communityString>
              <snmpVersion>2c</snmpVersion>
              <timeOut>1000</timeOut>
              <maxRetries>2</maxRetries>
              <OIDS>
                <OID>
                    <oid_label>System Usage Load</oid_label>
                    <oid>.1.3.6.1.4.1.14685.3.1.52.2</oid>
                    <oid_value>TBD</oid_value>
                    <alert_threshold>90</alert_threshold>
                </OID>
                <OID>
                    <oid_label>CPU Usage</oid_label>
                    <oid>.1.3.6.1.4.1.14685.3.1.14.3</oid>
                    <oid_value>TBD</oid_value>
                    <alert_threshold>90</alert_threshold>
                </OID>
              </OIDS>
       </host>
        <host>
              <ip>2.2.2.2</ip>
              <port>1161</port>
              <communityString>testcomm</communityString>
              <snmpVersion>2c</snmpVersion>
              <timeOut>1000</timeOut>
              <maxRetries>2</maxRetries>
              <OIDS>
                <OID>
                    <oid_label>System Usage Load</oid_label>
                    <oid>.1.3.6.1.4.1.14685.3.1.52.2</oid>
                    <oid_value>TBD</oid_value>
                    <alert_threshold>90</alert_threshold>
                </OID>
                <OID>
                    <oid_label>CPU Usage</oid_label>
                    <oid>.1.3.6.1.4.1.14685.3.1.14.3</oid>
                    <oid_value>TBD</oid_value>
                    <alert_threshold>90</alert_threshold>
                </OID>
              </OIDS>
       </host>
</hosts>
```

Thanks in advance.
Tufail

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  This question is *way* too broad, and is really several questions.  There are whole books written on the topic.  What do you mean by, "structure is OK?" Is it the syntax correct, or a good design?  Can't answer the latter, since that is subjective.  If you want to know how to read/write xml files in java, there are many tutorials - example -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/, and https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: 2) If you define a XSD (XML Schema) according to you can generate Java classed using XJC

Comment: Thanks Simas_ch, good suggestion